# I have to press matlab "Add to Path" button each time I open matlab, on Windows-7 Pro

Tags: matlab

What can I do to avoid this?
I saw a solution that said to use "set path" but I can't find how to do that.

Comment: Place all your folder with scripts you want to use in the MATLAB-root folder

Comment: That would be inconvenient.  How can I set the path to another arbitrary folder?

Comment: Google tells me this: http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/add-remove-or-reorder-folders-on-the-search-path.html

Comment: @thewaywewalk - It's a duplicate.  Marking as such.

Answer (score 0):

One way:

Create a file in the directory where Matlab opens called `startup.m`. In this file, add a line like,

```
addpath('path/to/include/folder1')
addpath('path/to/include/folder2')
```

and any other customization features you want. Maybe Google "Matlab startup example" for ideas if you're interested.

Alternatively, if you're only ever going to work in one folder, you could change the location where Matlab starts. The start folder is always added to the path.